# OpenMPI cannot fully utilize 10 GE

Tags: openmpi

I tried to perform data exchange between two machines connected with 10GE. The size of data is large enough (8 GB) to expect network utilization near the maximum. But surprisingly I observed absolutely different behavior.

To check the throughput I have used two different programs - `nethogs` and `nload`, both of them show that network utilization is much lower than expected. Moreover the results are unpredictable - sometimes in and out channels are utilized simultaneously, but sometimes transmission and reception are separated as if there is a half-duplex channel. Sample output of `nload`:

```
Device enp1s0f0 [192.168.0.11] (1/1):
======================================================================================================================
Incoming:




                                                      |||||||||||||||||||
                                                     .###################
                                                     ####################|
                                                     #####################      Curr: 0.00 GBit/s
                                                     #####################      Avg: 2.08 GBit/s
                                                    .#####################      Min: 0.00 GBit/s
                                                    #######################     Max: 6.32 GBit/s
                                                    #######################     Ttl: 57535.38 GByte
Outgoing:




                                  ||||||||||||||||||
                                  ##################
                                 |##################
                                 ###################|
                                 ####################                           Curr: 0.00 GBit/s
                                 ####################                           Avg: 2.09 GBit/s
                                .####################                           Min: 0.00 GBit/s
                                #####################.                          Max: 6.74 GBit/s
                                ######################                          Ttl: 57934.64 GByte
```

The code I use is here:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    boost::mpi::environment env{};
    boost::mpi::communicator world{};
    boost::mpi::request reqs[2];

    int k = 10;
    if(argc > 1)
        k = std::atoi(argv[1]);

    uint64_t n = (1ul << k);

    std::vector<std::complex<double>> sv(n, world.rank());
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> rv(n);

    int dest = world.rank() == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    int src = dest;

    world.barrier();
    reqs[0] = world.irecv(src, 0, rv.data(), n);
    reqs[1] = world.isend(dest, 0, sv.data(), n);
    boost::mpi::wait_all(reqs, reqs + 2);

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the command I use to run on cluster:

```
mpirun --mca btl_tcp_if_include 192.168.0.0/24 --hostfile ./host_file -n 2 --bind-to core /path/to/shared/folder/mpi_exp 29
```

`29` here means that 2^(29 + 4) = 8 GBytes will be sent

What I have done:

- Proved that there is no hardware problem by successful saturation of the channel with `netcat`.
- Checked with `tcpdump` that the size of TCP packets during the communication is unstable and rarely reach the maximum size (in `netcat` case it is stable).
- Checked with `strace` that socket operations are correct.
- Checked TCP parameters in `sysctl` - they are ok.

Could you please advise me why OpenMPI doesn't work as expected?

**EDIT (14.08.2018):**

Finally I was able to continue to dig into this problem. Below is the output of OSU bandwidth benchmark (it was run without any mca options):

```
# OSU MPI Bandwidth Test v5.3
# Size      Bandwidth (MB/s)
1                       0.50
2                       0.98
4                       1.91
8                       3.82
16                      6.92
32                     10.32
64                     22.03
128                    43.95
256                    94.74
512                   163.96
1024                  264.90
2048                  400.01
4096                  533.47
8192                  640.02
16384                 705.02
32768                 632.03
65536                 667.29
131072                842.00
262144                743.82
524288                654.09
1048576               775.50
2097152               759.44
4194304               774.81
```

Actually I think that such poor performance is caused by CPU bound. Each MPI  process is single-threaded by default, and it is just not able to saturate 10GE channel.

I know it is possible to communicate with several threads by enabling multithreading when building OpenMPI. But such approach will lead to increased complexity on application level.

So is it possible to have multithreaded sending/receiving in OpenMPI internally on the level responsible for point-to-point data transfer?

Comment: Which version of Open MPI are you using ? I strongly encourage you to use a well established benchmark such as IMB from Intel or the OSU suite, they include a warm-up phase and report the bandwidth directly.

Comment: What does `nload` count? Bytes sent to wire, whole ethernet frames or only the pay load, or maybe tcp/udp payload? Unstable TCP packet size is kinda suspicious. Maybe there is some buffer size mismatch, and you don't utilize whole bandwidth. Are you sure the medium and devices are physically capable of reaching 10Gbps speed? At those speeds the quality of connection (cable quality, length, interference etc.) makes a difference. There is many things that might affect your readings.

Comment: @luk32 Yes I'm sure the hardware is capable of 10Gbps. Firstly nodes are connected by optical fiber and are placed in the same rack. And secondly I was able to get maximum with netcat - sending output of /dev/zero - but with two pairs of processes, so maybe bottleneck is the CPU?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I tried 1.10 firstly and now use the last one from master branch 4.0.0a1. Will try a benchmark on Monday, thanks for advice

Comment: With old versions, you need to `mpirun --mca btl_tcp_sndbuf 0 --mca btl_tcp_rcvbuf 0 ...`. This is the default on recent versions.